# How to disable save and protected sheet prompt in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet which is protected, since the sheet is protected I don't want the user to save it, and I don't want the `save the sheet prompt` to appear when someone closes the workbook. Till now I have been using this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Using this code, save feature is disabled but the prompt is still appearing

**Similar problem:**
 Since the workbook is protected whenever someone tries to change the cell content it displays  an alert, I want to disable that prompt message as well.
Can someone help me to fix this

Comment: Add another `Workbook_BeforeClose` event with this code `Thisworkbook.Close False` to disable the appearance of prompt. As for the `protected sheet prompt`, I'm not sure if it is possible.

Comment: @L42 Hey, I used your suggestion and it works fine(it closes the workbook without any prompt message) except that it doesn't closes whole excel editor.

Comment: Then add this line `Application.Quit`. That will take care of it. The risk is it will close other workbooks as well although it will prompt if you wish to close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L42 has already answered part of your question.

> I want to disable that prompt message as well.

Do this. While protecting the sheet, unckeck the option `Select Locked Cells`. Now that will take care of the keyboard input while the sheet is locked and protected.

[image]

As for mouse inputs i.e the prompt showing up when you double click on the cell, use this :)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, I tried the code given by you but its not working, the double click mouse input is still showing prompt message

Comment: I can not uncheck >Select Locked Cells  as I have some some cells that I have added as exception because user input is required at those points. The double click event looks fine but it is  not working

Comment: Hey, the double click event is working, by mistake I copied it into the ThisWorkbook VBA page

Comment: Why is that when I uncheck "Select Locked cells" during protecting the sheet the ranges that I have added as exceptions (using allow users to edit ranges in the Review tab of excel) also become non editable